# How to get Absolute XPath in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, xpath

As written in the question I need the **absolute** Xpath and not the relative one.

I mean, I need something like this:

```
html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h4[1]/b
```

and not like this:

```
//*[@class='featured-box']//*[text()='Testing']
```

On both browsers when I inspect the code and I use right click -> copy XPath
I am getting the relative Path.

Please note, I am using Firefox Quantum and I cannot use firebug or firepath because they are not supported.

Comment: Look here for [A Quora Answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-extension-for-Xpath-for-Chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl

After that, click at icon of the extension and, after two boxes appers in the tab window, hold shift key to navigate between elements and see the xpath.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome,for relative Xpath we use "Copy as Xpath" and  for absolute Xpath use "Copy as full Xpath"

Comment: In Firefox new versions we just need to navigate to Copy->XPath to get full path. There is no option to get absolute XPath with default developer tools.