# How to get Absolute XPath in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I need to get absolute Xpath and not the relative one.

I need something like this:

```
html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h4[1]/b
```

On both browsers when I inspect the code and I use right click -> copy XPath I am getting the relative Path.

Any tool or plugin available to get absolute path.

Please note, I am using selenium webdriver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49396361/5752558 Does this answer help you?

Comment: You have `copy full xpath` option. But you should use the relative xpath, not the absolute xpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Absolute XPath in Chrome or Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48022185/how-to-get-absolute-xpath-in-chrome-or-firefox)

Answer (score 3):

To get the absolute path in: 
**Chrome Browser (v79):** Right-click WebPage -> Inspect -> Right-click on web element -> Copy -> Copy Full Xpath (This gives you absolute XPath)

**Firefox browser (v72):** Right-click webpage -> Inspect Element -> Right-click on web element -> Copy -> XPath (If the web element has any unique id then it will give you the relative XPath otherwise it will give absolute XPath). To get the absolute XPath for an element having a unique id, delete the unique id in the inspector window and again copy the XPath you will get the absolute XPath.

Answer (score 1):

To retrive the *absolute* [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) from the *Browser Console* you can follow the steps mentioned below:

1. Open the url https://demoqa.com/button/ in *Google Chrome* browser.
2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools).
3. Within `Elements` tab, click on the element `Inspector` tool:

[image: element_inspector]

4. [Mouse Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261078/how-to-mouse-hover-using-java-through-selenium-webdriver-and-java/47261894#47261894) over the desired element and the element gets highlighted within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)

[image: desired_element]

5. **Right Click** on the element within the HTML, select **Copy** and select **Copy XPath**

[image: copy_xpath]

6. You will get the absolute xpath as:

   ```
   //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/input
   ```

Comment: //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/input is not an absolute XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want `Absolute Xpath`. If you want to locate with Xpath only then highly recommended `Relative Xpath`.

Absolute Xpath will change if your current UI change`(html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h4[1]/b)` . Like if added extra div or section or any element.

Comment: I want to get absolute path, any tool availabe to get absolute path

Comment: You can get by inspect element or you can try some extension which are available to get xpath. (XPath Helper for Chrome)